# Why I never see the Hello text in Console in this program?

Tags: c, malloc, osx-yosemite, memset

This is the code I have, running on **OS X Yosemite**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    while (1) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = rand();
        printf("Allocating\n");
        int *pi = malloc(5000000 * sizeof(int));
        if(pi==NULL){
            printf("Hello");
        }
        memset(pi, r, 5000000 * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

So this program eventually stops running, last lines in Console I see being:

> Allocating
>
> Allocating
>
> Allocating
>
> Killed: 9
>
> Korays-MacBook-Pro:hello2 koraytugay$

If malloc does not return NULL in this situation, when will it do? My understanding is a memory allocation problem happens here, but why "Hello" is not printed?

Comment: `printf()` is buffered; not all output is written instantly. Immediately after the `printf()` call, you try to write a large amount of data to `NULL` - I'd imagine the program crashes without attempting to flush the output.

Comment: @PaulRoub Let me try.

Comment: You should not be calling memset again after the look, and put a "break" in the if statements after the printf.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Why not and why?

Comment: Take a look to [What is the correct way to handle “out of memory”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439977/what-is-the-correct-way-to-handle-out-of-memory)

Comment: @PaulRoub I tried fflush(stdout); no difference..

Comment: While you're at it....you're not using rand() for anything, but before you do, take srand() OUTSIDE THE LOOP.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker What do you mean I am not using it for anything? I am writing the result to memory.

Comment: Are you running on Linux?

Comment: Koray write about your OS next time, it caused dispute in your previous question :)

Comment: Actually the answers along with comments for previous question are giving a full answer to this one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not really. Here I am writing to the memory I allocated..

Comment: Exactly. An this behaviour is explained by @blindy. Here it gets killed when you are writing to the memory, which was overcommitted by `malloc`

Comment: My mistake, you're right. Still, move srand() outside the loop or you won't be getting random numbers.

Comment: Did you read the linked answer? Did you try what user2407394 suggests in the answer? If the behaviour is similar to Linux (>=2.6) then it should work.

Comment: the line that calls memset to set the ~20meg of memory to 'r' will not work as you expect.  the second parameter to memset will only take a char, not an int.  and 'r' is an int.  It may get properly demoted (probably not) but even then only the least significant 8 bits of the int will be used. to set the memory

Comment: I am not real familiar with OS-X, but in linux more memory will be allocated by the OS to satisfy the malloc until both main memory and virtual memory are exhausted. (amongst other things, this will result in lots of 'thrashing' of paged memory as a page is only 4k and each malloc/memset is working with ~20megs of memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux will kill the program if your memory requirement exceeds available memory making malloc never return NULL.

You can turn this feature off using echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that printf queues "Hello" for output, then you try to memset with null pointer and process gets killed before queued "Hello" is processed. You can try flushing stdout after Hello (fflush).

Comment: where did you place the call to fflush()?